# fixing Request Entity Too Large when using WCF on xamarin

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin app that consumes a WCF service. i an transferring byte arrays that are bitmaps from the client to the service.
For whatever reason i can upload an image through the wcf service using the test client, and everything works perfectly. however when i attempt to do it through the xamarin app i fails with the "Request Entity Too Large" error. Also retrieving said large images through the service works fine in the app, the only problem is sending the images to the service. I generated the client code using SlSvcUtil.exe I have tried just about everything, I'm not sure what the problem is.

**Web.config on server:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="3072000"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
        preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**Service declaration in app:**

```
    YardSaleClient service;
    public YardSaleServiceImplementation()
    {
        try
        {
            BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding()
            {
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = 3000000,
                MaxBufferSize = 3000000,
                SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
            };

            service = new YardSaleClient(
            httpBinding,
            new EndpointAddress(Constants.WCFURL));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

        }
```

**Output.config generated for client**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IYardSale" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:9617/YardSaleService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IYardSale"
                contract="IYardSale" name="BasicHttpBinding_IYardSale" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```